# VB2010 How to tell if a number is a whole integer

Tags: vb.net, numbers, integer

I need to be able to tell if an integer is a whole number or if it has decimals. So 13 would be a whole number and 23.23 would be a decimal.

So like;

```
If 13 is a whole number then
msgbox("It's a whole number, with no decimals!")
else
msgbox("It has a decimal.")
end if
```

Comment: What type is the variable that you are using to contain your number, is it a string?.

Answer (score 25):

```
If x = Int(x) Then 
  'x is an Integer!'
Else
  'x is not an Integer!'
End If
```

Comment: What happens when x is a string? i.e. "2", "2.2", "3.14"? Or even better yet, what happens when x is larger than 2.1 billion? Whole numbers (i.e. table IDs) can and do exceed the max value you can store in an Int (@ 2.1 billion).

Comment: I assumed strict typing. You'd get an overflow exception if the number is too large for the variable.

Answer (score 11):

You can check whether the floor and ceiling of the number is the same or not. If it equals, then it is a whole integer, else it will be different.

```
If Math.Floor(value) = Math.Ceiling(value) Then
...
Else
...
End If
```

Comment: Or you can try if `Math.Truncate(value) = value`

Answer (score 5):

Judging by the fact that you have one type that you are needing to determine whether or not it is an Integer or another Type I am assuming that the number is contained in a string.  If so you can use the [Integer.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) Method to determine if the value is an Integer, it will also output it as an integer if it is successful.  If this isn't what you are doing please update your question with more information.

```
Dim number As String = 34.68
Dim output As Integer
If (Integer.TryParse(number, output)) Then
    MsgBox("is an integer")
Else
    MsgBox("is not an integer")
End If
```

Edit:

You can use the same idea if you are using a Decimal or another Type to contain your number,n something like this.

```
Option Strict On
Module Module1

    Sub Main()

        Dim number As Decimal = 34
        If IsInteger(number) Then
            MsgBox("is an integer")
        Else
            MsgBox("is not an integer")
        End If
        If IsInteger("34.62") Then
            MsgBox("is an integer")
        Else
            MsgBox("is not an integer")
        End If

    End Sub

    Public Function IsInteger(value As Object) As Boolean
        Dim output As Integer ' I am not using this by intent it is needed by the TryParse Method
        If (Integer.TryParse(value.ToString(), output)) Then
            Return True
        Else
            Return False
        End If
    End Function
End Module
```

Comment: Sorry, I have updated the original post. The input is always going to be an integer but I need to find out if it's a whole number or if the integer has any decimal places.

Comment: @user2691270 an [Integer](http://www.techterms.com/definition/integer) cannot have a decimal point, if has a decimal point it is either a Decimal, Double, String or Single or something along those lines. Where is this number being generated from, if a Textbox it is probably a string.

Comment: @MarkHall: You dont need the "helper" variable for TryParse if you are not interested in the result. You can either pass a constant (like 0, -1, 42 or whatever), or "nothing" (which defaults to 0 for an integer).
As a sidenote: Since the OP only specified "whole number", I'd suggest to use BigInteger.TryParse.

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim Num As String = "54.54"
If Num.Contains(".") Then MsgBox("Decimal") 
'Do Something
```

Comment: Some elaboration and explanation would improve the quality of this answer.

Comment: This answer is the only one that checks if the number (as a string) is formatted correctly. The other answers equate 1 to 1.00 and this is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that your initial value is a string.

**1**, First check if the string value is numeric. 
**2**, Compare the floor and ceiling of the number. If it's the same, you have a whole number.

I prefer using extension methods.

```
''' <summary>
''' Is Numeric
''' </summary>
''' <param name="p_string"></param>
''' <returns></returns>
''' <remarks></remarks>
<Extension()>
Public Function IsNumeric(ByVal p_string As String) As Boolean
    If Decimal.TryParse(p_string, Nothing) Then Return True
    Return False
End Function

''' <summary>
''' Is Integer
''' </summary>
''' <param name="p_stringValue"></param>
''' <returns></returns>
<Extension()>
Public Function IsInteger(p_stringValue As String) As Boolean
    If Not IsNumeric(p_stringValue) Then Return False
    If Math.Floor(CDec(p_stringValue)) = Math.Ceiling(CDec(p_stringValue)) Then Return True
    Return False
End Function
```

**Example**:

```
    Dim _myStringValue As String = "200"
    If _myStringValue.IsInteger Then
        'Is an integer
    Else
        'Not an integer
    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if x Mod 1 = 0
  'x is an Integer!'
Else
  'x is not an Integer!'
End If
```